# Consultar base de datos por partes

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy buscando una forma de hacer que mi base de datos se muestre por partes.
Es decir, primero las 10 primeras filas, al presionar un boton, realizar una consulta con las otras 10, y asi hasta el final.
He buscado en internet y solo he encontrado la clausla LIMIT, que me permite mostrar los 10 primeros. Pero a partir de ahi, ¿como hago para que me muestre los 10 que siguen?

Comment: No es muy claro tu pregunta? Pero creo que estas intentando crear una paginación de productos o contenido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la documentación de [`MYSQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#id1026131), puedes pasarle dos argumentos a `LIMIT` en donde el primero indica la distancia al primer registro de tu tabla y el segundo la cantidad de registros.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Devuelve 10 registros a partir de la 6
```

En tu caso particular sería:

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 LIMIT 10,10;
```

Comment: Por alguna razón no se formó correctamente el enlace que hace referencia a la documentación. La respuesta es correctísima.

Comment: @toledano Gracias, si eso estaba viendo, no se cual puede ser el error, ya busque de editar la rta, y no tuve suerte. Saludos

Comment: @Mariano muchas gracias Mariano

Answer (score 0):

> No es muy claro tu pregunta? Pero creo que estas intentando crear una paginación de productos o contenido?

Crear una paginación es más factible mucho más mejor de esta manera puedes mostrar 10 productos y luego mostar 10 más y así sucesivamente hasta llegar el final de los registros de la base de datos.

```
//$registros nos entrega la cantidad de registros a mostrar.
$registros = 10;

//$contador como su nombre lo indica el contador.   
$contador = 1;

/**
 * Se inicia la paginación, si el valor de $pagina es 0 le asigna el valor 1 e $inicio entra con valor 0.
 * si no es la pagina 1 entonces $inicio sera igual al numero de pagina menos 1 multiplicado por la cantidad de registro
 */
if (!$pagina) { 
$inicio = 0; 
$pagina = 1; 
} else { 
$inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $registros; 
} 
?>
<!-- Se crea la tabla que mostrara los datos tabulados -->
<table>
    <caption>Registros</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
            <th>Continente</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody> 
        <?php
        /**
         * Se inicia la consulta donde seleccionamos todos los campos de la tabla personas, pero donde isActive = 1, esto lo hacemos para el manejo
         * de registros si están activos o no.
         */
        $resultados = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM personas WHERE isActive = '1'");

        //Contamos la cantidad de filas entregadas por la consulta, de esta forma sabemos cuantos registros fueron retornados por la consulta.
        $total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultados); 

        //Generamos otra consulta la cual creara en si la paginación, ordenando y creando un límite en las consultas.
        $resultados = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM personas WHERE isActive = '1' ORDER BY Nombre ASC LIMIT $inicio, $registros");  

        //Con ceil redondearemos el resultado total de las paginas 4.53213 = 5
        $total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $registros);                   

        // Si tenemos un retorno en la variable $total_registro iniciamos el ciclo para mostrar los datos.
        if ($total_registros) {
            while ($personas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            ?>      
                <!-- Muestra de Datos usando el comodin <?=$variable; ?> es lo mismo que <?php echo $variable; ?> -->
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$contador;?></td>    
                    <td><?=$personas["Nombre"];?></td>
                    <td><?=$personas["Ciudad"];?></td>
                    <td><?=$personas["Pais"];?></td>
                    <td><?=$personas["Continente"];?></td>
                </tr>       

                <?php           
                /**
                 * La variable $contador es la misma que iniciamos arriba con valor 1, en cada ciclo sumara 1 a este valor.
                 * $contador sirve para mostrar cuantos registros tenemos, es mas que nada una guía.
                 */
               $contador++;
            }       
         } else {
          echo "<font color='darkgray'>(sin resultados)</font>";
        }

        mysqli_free_result($resultados);    
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>   
    <?php
    if ($total_registros) {
        /**
         * Acá activamos o desactivamos la opción "< Anterior", si estamos en la pagina 1 nos dará como resultado 0 por ende NO
         * activaremos el primer if y pasaremos al else en donde se desactiva la opción anterior. Pero si el resultado es mayor
         * a 0 se activara el href del link para poder retroceder.
         */
        if (($pagina - 1) > 0) {
            echo "<a href='paginacion.php?pagina=".($pagina-1)."'>< Anterior</a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='#'>< Anterior</a>";
        }

        // Generamos el ciclo para mostrar la cantidad de paginas que tenemos.
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++) {
            if ($pagina == $i) {
                echo "<a href='#'>". $pagina ."</a>"; 
            } else {
                echo "<a href='paginacion.php?pagina=$i'>$i</a> "; 
            }   
        }

        /**
         * Igual que la opción primera de "< Anterior", pero acá para la opción "Siguiente >", si estamos en la ultima pagina no podremos
         * utilizar esta opción.
         */
        if (($pagina + 1)<=$total_paginas) {
            echo "<a href='paginacion.php?pagina=".($pagina+1)."'>Siguiente ></a>";
        } else {
            echo "<a href='#'>Siguiente ></a>";
        }        
    }
    ?>  
</div> 

<?php
    // Cerramos conexión con MySQLi.
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```